# Better way to do debug-logging?

Tags: c++, c, logging

Is there a better, maybe more industry standard way to turn on and off debug logging throughout your code?

What I have currently is something similar to this:

```
#define logging

[.. in several places throughout the code ..]

#ifdef logging
   cout << "My debug messages\n";
#endif
```

I just comment out the `#define logging` when it's no longer needed.
A couple of shortcomings with this approach seem to be:

- I have to `#define logging` in every file I want to use it in
- It's not very robust; I would prefer something like `#define logging 1`, and be able to check which *logging-level* is enabled to determine the granularity of my debug output. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, `#ifdef` doesn't care what value you choose, it just cares that it's *defined*

Are there any suggestions on how to better implement this?

Comment: There is no need to define it in every file, e.g. compile with option `-Dlogging`

Comment: Amazing how often this is asked.

Comment: There are many frameworks that's made just for logging. They already deal with this, and much more.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : any *nix compatible suggestions? :)

Comment: @ctote _'any *nix compatible suggestions?'_ Tons of, e.g. [log4cxx](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Log4cxx.html)

Comment: syslog/rsyslogd works for linux.  Other than the conf file, you can use setlogmask (I think that's what it is called anyway) to control the log level from inside your own application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not very robust; I would prefer something like `#define logging 1`, and be able to check which logging-level is enabled to determine the granularity of my debug output.

Well why don't you do that? Just don't test with `#ifdef`, but with `#if`:

```
#if logging>1
  // something
#endif
```

Also - you could define `logging` in a separate file (like `myDefines.h`) and include it in your other files.

```
//myDefines.h
#define logging 2

//someOtherFile.h
#include "myDefines.h"

#if logging>1
   // something
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

**One suggestion:**

You can `#define logging` in your project settings instead of in every file that you want to use it in.

Comment: Project settings? I assume using an IDE of some sort? I'm not currently (regularly) using an IDE for my projects.

Comment: Well, in that case you should probably define it in a common header file (unless you want different logging-levels for different modules in your application).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout Google's glog project: https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/
But this might be more overhead than your're looking for.

Something simple you can try, granted your
 compiler supports the -Dmacroname flag, you can turn 
on logging with during compile time. For example:

```
g++ -Dlogging program.cpp -o program
```

will define the logging macro to 1.